# Translate google

Tags: javascript, button, google-translate

The problem is that, when I select a language I google the band that opens. Here is my code:

```
<! - Begin TranslateThis Button ->

<div id="translate-this">
    <a href="http://translateth.is/" class="translate-this-button">
    <img src = ".. / modules / traduireshop / images / FR. jpg "alt =" "style =" border: 0 "/>
    </ a>
</ div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"> </ script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js"> </ script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // javascript - see below
</ script>

<! - End TranslateThis Button ->
```

And the address of my site is: http://www.lecoindesvelos.com

```
TranslateThis ({
    undoText: 'Undo', '
    panelText 'Translate Into:'
    moreText: More Languages ??'36 "'
    busyText: 'Translating page ...'
    CancelText: 'cancel',
    ddLangs: [
        'fr',
        'en',
        'of'
        'it'
        'es',   
    ],
    noBtn: true
});
```

Could you tell me where I have a problem.
I would like to have this band more.

Comment: You miss a number of quotes and commas in your object syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your object's syntax was incorrect, try this instead:

```
TranslateThis({
    undoText: 'Undo',
    panelText: 'Translate Into:',
    moreText: "More Languages '36'",
    busyText: 'Translating page ...',
    CancelText: 'cancel',
    ddLangs: [
        'fr',
        'en',
        'of',
        'it',
        'es'
    ],
    noBtn: true
});
```

---

Also, you are closing some html tags incorrectly:

```
    </ a>
</ div>
```

That should be:

```
    </a>
</div>
```

---

And last, these HTML comments are missing some dashes:

```
<! - Begin TranslateThis Button ->
```

Try this:

```
<!-- Begin TranslateThis Button -->
```

Comment: The syntax is as good on my site the problem is mainly the google toolbar that appears.

Answer (score 0):

You've got unmatched quotes and missing commas in your object creation. The correct code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    TranslateThis ({
        undoText: 'Undo', //removed a quote
        panelText: 'Translate Into:', //added a colon after key and added comma
        moreText: 'More Languages (36)', //removed unmatched quote, added comma
        busyText: 'Translating page ...', //added comma
        CancelText: 'cancel', 
        ddLangs: [
            'fr',
            'en',
            'of', //added comma
            'it', //added comma
            'es' //removed comma - it's the end of the array, so no need
        ],
        noBtn: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your code does not work moreText bad syntax widget no longer opens
My problem is mainly that the google banner opens.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the 'Translate This' Button’s service http://translateth.is is down. The demo running on that site isn’t working either.

Firebug shows that your site tries to access `http://85.17.190.170:9013/socket.io/1/?t=1356094015380`, which isn’t responding).

Also, your question is incomplete:

> The problem is that, when I select a language I google the band that
>   opens.

When happens when you select a language?  You say you "Google the band that opens"; do you mean that you perform a Google search for the band that opens?  (I guess not, I’m just guessing here).
Or do you mean that you’d like to see more languages listed?

Comment: By clicking on the flag of the language I google iframe that opens.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you mean by that. (Tu pourrais décrire le problème en Français ?)